# Как принять почту и распотрошить тело письма?

Tags: php, email

Как лучше принять почту и распотрошить тело письма? В идеале хочется из тела письма вырезать и сохранять локально все картинки. Если с разбором письма проблем думаю не будет - то вот чем принять почту определенного ящика даже не знаю.

Comment: Принять можно там же, где и отправляли.

Comment: Я планирую отправлять письма со сканера, на нем есть турбо кнопка, а принимать хочу в офисе. Так вот, чем лучше принять почту что бы в эой же срезе ее и порезать на кусочки ?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы письма бы обрабатывал по imap.

в php есть функции imap_* для работы с ящиком.
[php cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch17_04.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Принять можно любым почтовым клиентом, который умеет передавать принятое письмо на обработку внешним утилитам. Но если хочется своим, и непременно на PHP, то смотреть в сторону [PECL::POP3](http://pecl.php.net/package/POP3), или [сюда](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=pop3&go_search=1).